# Xamarin Studio Android - Unable to create HelloWorld with Latest and Greatest Platform

Tags: android, xamarin, mono

I've created a new project, selected "Android App" , "Latest and Greatest" and as theme "Material". Also, I'm intalling Google Play services.

After this, I try running the app created by default, and get the following error (on my phone and genymotion emulator).

```
[art] Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
[AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[AndroidRuntime] Process: Memetizame.Memetizame, PID: 5804
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_22 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4967)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4559)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4499)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_22 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:38)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4964)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 11 more
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Xamarin.Android.Platform
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:281)
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:32)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Did you download the SDK from the SDK manager?

Comment: Yes, I installed literally everything available for API 21.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make changes in "Target Version". (If you are using Visual Studio, then you need to change "Compile version" too.)

If you are working in Xamarin Studio, then double click on your project; "Project Options" will open, then click on "General" and change "Target Version" (select appropriate version from drop-down).

For Visual Studio:

1. In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the project that you want to change, and then choose Properties.
2. In the left column of the properties window, choose the Application tab.
3. In the "Compile using Android Version" and Target Framework list, choose the version that you want.
4. In the verification dialog box that appears, choose the Yes button.

I hope this solution solves your problem.