# Visual Studio Xamarin android app crashes

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to run an android xamarin app in Visual Studio 2013, it deploys normally, but crashes after start.

Here is the log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_22 or Xamarin.Android.Pla
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5002)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_22 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:38)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Xamarin.Android.Platform
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:281)
    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:32)
```

The same thing on emulator with any platform and device.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Same problem here, but with Xamarin Studio

Answer (score 0):

With the last Xamarin Update i run into this problem as well.
Try disabling "Use shared runtime" in your Android Build options. It seems with the current Version a developent build is not able to call into the shared mono runtime.

--> https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52439/unable-to-get-provider-mono-monoruntimeprovider

---

What helped some others:
Some suggested to just change "Target Version" (and "Compile Version" for VS) and Rebuild. The important part was to have changes in the Project File and not what exactly you changed "Target Version" from and to.

--> https://stackoverflow.com/a/32607524/383658